# Application.Workbooks.Open method intermittently fails in Excel 2208 with Sharepoint-hosted source files

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

I am using the following line to open external workbooks to read data, using VBA from an XLAM add-in:

```
Set MB_WB = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path, UpdateLinks:=xlUpdateLinksAlways, ReadOnly:=True)
```

MB_WB is explicitly dimensioned as a Workbook object, and 'path' is a String that the user enters in a table (of multiple source documents) in Excel, and I read in via some unimportant intermediate steps - one key detail is that I already preprocess the string that ends up in 'path' to 'clean' Sharepoint clutter out of the string (the ":x:/r/" bit and the trailing "?..." after the file name). I also do a precheck to see if 'path' is already open, as this has behaved weirdly with the .Open method in some previous builds of Excel; so by the time I get to the above code line, I know my path is 'clean' (no Sharepoint junk in it) and I know the file is closed.

The symptoms:

- For all users (of order 100) using Excel version 2203, this works flawlessly - the file is opened in the background (no GUI) and the rest of my code can extract the required data and then close the source file(s) again.
- For a handful of users who have recently been 'upgraded' to Excel version 2208, the VBA code sometimes works, but sometimes doesn't (MB_WB ends up being Nothing, so I have to handle it with an error message to the user). It will work and then not work with the same file in the same Sharepoint location, just at different times (for the same user).

I have, of course, got the users to check the path (cleaned up) is actually valid i.e. my link-cleaner code is robust. Also, if they manually open the source files first, then the code runs fine (as I mentioned, I do a precheck on whether the source(s) is open and grab the Workbook object without using Workbooks.Open) - this suggests it is not a user-permissions issue, or other problem with the source files themselves.

Our corporate environment uses Windows Defender for av and I see no 'Risky action blocked' messages in the Protection History on the affected machines (this has been an issue in the past, with VBA-spawned objects, but that was using CreateObject, which is different to this issue I think).

Does anyone have any suggestions on even where to look to isolate the problem? Could it be something to do with checkin/checkout functionality on Sharepoint where the source files are located? Despite my use of ReadOnly:=True? But then why would it work OK with Excel 2203 (I am aware this could be coincidence, and that it is chance that the affected users are all using version 2208).

Comment: A bit more detail has just emerged - when the affected user opens the target source file(s) that are causing the error, he sees an unresolved save conflict in Excel. So I am guessing we are maybe seeing a symptom of trying to use Workbooks.Open with a file that has unresolved conflicts? Manually resolving the conflicts and closing the files without saving, and then trying the code again seemed to fix it.

I am then probably going to have to post a different question about how the conflicts arose in the first place!

Comment: Maybe it would help avoiding the error to set `MB_WB.AutoSaveOn = False` immediately after opening, considering you don't want to save any changes anyways? Also btw. I think it's better to add the additional information to your original post as an edit instead of as a comment :)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback on editing my OP - I will do that in future.
Re your suggestion, I don't believe it gets that far i.e. Excel cannot find the specified path for some reason. Unless the user manually opens the file, no Workbook object is ever created...

Comment: I proposed this because you mentioned this behavior was caused by unresolved save conflicts. If you always set `.AutoSaveOn = False`, this might prevent the save conflicts from occurring in the first place, hence avoiding the problem in the future.

Comment: Aha, I understand, thanks - I will see if this reduces/eliminates the issue frequency.